# How to get player ID in android Java with One Signal 5.0.2?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

In previous versions if one signal, we can get the player ID in android Java using the following line.

`OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId()`

But this method does not work in One Signal 5.0.2. So how can I get that ID now?

I tried all possible solutions from the internet but those methods does not work with One Signal 5.0.2. As it's the latest version and proper documentation is not yet available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/fetch-aliases

***OneSignal is in the process of migrating from a device-centric model (player ID) to a new user-centric data model (OneSignal ID). In the new user-centric world, Users have a OneSignal ID, and what was the player ID is now known as the Subscription ID.***

Get Subscription ID
`OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.id`

One Signal 5.0.0+